# How to avoid a web app timout whilst data-crunching?

Tags: python-3.x, web-applications, web-scraping, pythonanywhere

Now my Python web app spends so much time data-crunching that PythonAnywhere assumes that the app has crashed and times out. (>5 mins = timeout)

My plan is (ultimately) to deliver the output to users by email, so they dont have to wait around anyway. ("Please check your email in 10 mins for your report").

I thought about doing a screen "refresh" periodically during the data-crunching to keep pythonanywhere happy - BUT if users close the browser then this isnt going to work.

How can I avoid a timeout and keep the app running for 10-15 mins without a browser?

Joe

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here -- I think we've already discussed this over email, but I'll post what I said here just in case it's useful for other people.

A good option for stuff that takes a long time to run is to refactor it into a script that you can run periodically, and then schedule that on the "Tasks" tab.  If you have a paid account, you can schedule up to 20 hourly tasks (we can bump that up if you need more), so to make the script run every (say) ten minutes, you could schedule it at 2 past the hour, 12 past the hour, and so on.   If you need the script to process data that comes from the user via your website, you could make your view write something to the database with the details of what needs doing, then the scheduled task could pick that up, process it, and put the results in the DB for the website to pick up.

We've got a help page with a bit more information [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AsyncInWebApps/).